# Is it possible to know what exactly changed using an observer in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, observer-pattern

I need send an email alert when the price of a product changes.
Is it possible do this with `ActiveRecord::Observer` or do I need use programming logic in the edit form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Dirty Objects](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects) in order to achieve that, in this specific case, you'll have something like this in your observer.

```
FooMailer.deliver_alert(foo) if foo.price_changed?
```

According to: "*Once you save a dirty object it clears out its changed state tracking and is once again considered unchanged*" You should ask for the `prince_changed?` before the `save` operation is done.

Hope It helps you.

Comment: My mystake in grammar. I want to send the alert when the price changes, not "only" the price. What I tried to meant was I don't want alert when other attributes change. Sorry. I edited my question. Can you update your answer?